# How to handle custom taxonomy archive when no posts will have that taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, post-meta

I have a hobby site where I record the changing tenants of a big shopping centre. For each tenant I create a post and use a ACF repeater to store the unit they are in and open/close dates. The unit uses a custom taxonomy called `unit_num`. Posts will not have this taxonomy assigned to them (like how post categories and tags are).

Screenshot of ACF repeater in the editor:
[image: ACF repeater in editor]

I would like to view the `unit_num` taxonomy archive (defaults to site.com/unit_num/123) and have it query the ACF repeater for tenants that have that taxonomy. Right now it (correctly) says no posts found.

Should I disable the taxonomy archive (public => false) and create a custom permalink (with add_rewrite_tag/add_rewrite_rule)?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do what I suggested at the end of the post:

- `public => false` in the taxonomy settings
- Add `add_rewrite_tag`/`add_rewrite_rule` to 'unit_num'
  and add a `pre_get_posts` action to tweak the query when `get_query_parm('unit_num')` is set.

This is all working well now.
(Often when you write a problem out on a forum it triggers a new outlook on the issue)